# mongodb aggregate - flatten array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Have below document collection, was trying to group and concatenate site + items keys to produce array. However with map function, each result returned as array. Final output under `siteitems` is a nested array. how can it be flattened?

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64ddcb04756827cb9d4633ba"
  },
  "site": "site1",
  "group": "env1",
  "items": {
    "x": {
      "release": "true"
    },
    "y": {
      "release": "true"
    },
    "z": {
      "release": "true"
    }
  }
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64ddcb04756827cb9d4633cd"
  },
  "site": "site2",
  "group": "env1",
  "items": {
    "x": {
      "release": "true"
    },
    "y": {
      "release": "true"
    },
    "z": {
      "release": "true"
    }
  }
}]
```

Getting below output

```
  {
    "_id": "env1",
    "siteitems": [["site1x", "site1y", "site1z"], ["site2x", "site2y", "site2z"]]
  }
```

tried below aggregate pipeline, returns a nested array, how can it be flattened?

```
[
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$group",
      siteitems: {
        $push: {
          $map: {
            input: {
              $objectToArray: "$items",
            },
            as: "item",
            in: {
              $concat: [
                "$site",
                "$$item.k",
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
]
```

Mongo [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Gx6PCGdrK3Q)

Comment: Can you please add the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `$set` stage with `$reduce` operator to concat each array into single array via `$concatArrays` operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$group",
      siteitems: {
        $push: {
          $map: {
            input: {
              $objectToArray: "$items"
            },
            as: "item",
            in: {
              $concat: [
                "$site",
                "$$item.k"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      siteitems: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$siteitems",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EMNRiUrFwJk)